# Pytest raises not working for custom exception

Tags: python, exception, pytest, isinstance

I have the following defined in an exceptions.py file:

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base exception raised by api wrapper"""

    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)


# HTTP response exceptions
class ApiBadRequestError(Error):
    """Bad Request –- Incorrect parameters."""

    def __init__(self, message: str):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)
```

I then have a function that correctly raises an `ApiBadRequestError` exception.

In pytest I'm doing the following:

```
 def test_handle_request_response_raises_correct_exception_for_response_code(
        self, status_code, exception_type, client, create_response
    ):
        response = create_response(status_code=status_code)

        with pytest.raises(ApiBadRequestError) as e:
            a = client._check_response_codes(response)
```

which is failing the test because inside `pytest.raises` it's doing `isintance(e, ApiBadRequestError)` which is returning False. If I however change the test to the following:

```
 def test_handle_request_response_raises_correct_exception_for_response_code(
        self, status_code, exception_type, client, create_response
    ):
        response = create_response(status_code=status_code)

        with pytest.raises(Exception) as e:
            a = client._check_response_codes(response)
```

it passes as the raised exception is seen as an instance of `Exception` even though it's an `ApiBadRequestError`

Any help would be really appreciated as I'm completely stumped here.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Seems like your function doesn't correctly raise `ApiBadRequestError` (or your test doesn't - something else might be happening), but something else happens instead? Otherwise `isinstance(e, ApiBadRequestError)` would be `True`.

Comment: How do you solve this problem?